# Tag view scrolls works only fixed height inside the UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I had a tag view inside the UITableview. so the tag view scroll works only the fixed height. how can i overcome if i scrolls the tag view upward direction it has to detected the UItableview scrolls and if the UItableview scroll downward it has to detected the tag view scrolls.

Comment: disable the scrolling of scroll view

Comment: but if lot of item on that tag view it will not scrolling..that is the problem

Comment: how can i get the dynamic height of the tag view inside the uitableview